# Metal color attachment supported pixel formats

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

For offscreen buffer rendering (not drawing on screen), does Metal on iOS supports MTLPixelFormatR32Uint as pixel format? In other words, is something like this supposed to work?

```
 let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
 pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor
 pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
 pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
 pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .R32Uint;
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [Metal Feature Set Tables document](https://developer.apple.com/metal/capabilities/) from Apple. It's currently a PDF. It used to be HTML. Anyway, there you will find a table showing which pixel formats are available for what purpose(s) in each versions of each OS. R32UInt is usable as a render target on all versions of all OSes.